# Data type casting between HttpResponse to Dictionary Object

Tags: android

Can Some One explain me how to change HttpResponse Object to Dictionary Object in Android. This is serious . Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You most likely receive the response as either JSON or XML. If it is JSON, there are `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`. If it is an XML, the options are more numerous. Android has no Dictionary class, the closest analogs to Python dictionaries are JSON and `HashMap`/`TreeMap` (or other `Map`s).

Finally, it is possible that you receive the data as plain text.

So you first find out what data does your server send, and then formulate a different question.

Comment: My team leader ask me to get JSon object reply from php code to receive without using looping . Sorry for disturb

Comment: You have to ask a different question